# Protobuf generated file doesn't recognize import path

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, importerror, protobuf-go

I have a proto file `product.proto` and I want to use it in `catalog.proto`. I can successfully import `product.proto` in `catalog.proto` but auto-generated `catalog.pb.go` is not able to reconize the path of its dependency i.e. `product.pb.go`. It states:

> could not import catalog/pb/entities (cannot find package "catalog/pb/entities" in any of
> /usr/local/go/src/catalog/pb/entities (from $GOROOT)
> /Users/trimulabs/go/src/catalog/pb/entities (from $GOPATH))

**Directory structure**

```
catalog
 ┣ main
 ┃ ┣ client.go
 ┃ ┗ server.go
 ┣ pb
 ┃ ┣ entities
 ┃ ┃ ┣ product.pb.go
 ┃ ┃ ┗ product.proto
 ┃ ┣ catalog.pb.go
 ┃ ┗ catalog.proto
```

**catalog.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";
package catalog;
import "catalog/pb/entities/product.proto";

service CatalogService {
    rpc PostProduct (PostProductRequest) returns (PostProductResponse) {}
    rpc GetProduct (GetProductRequest) returns (GetProductResponse) {}
    rpc GetProducts (GetProductsRequest) returns (GetProductsResponse) {}
}
```

**product.proto**

```
message Product {
    string id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    string description = 3;
    double price = 4;
}
message PostProductRequest {
    string name = 1;
    string description = 2;
    double price = 3;
}
message PostProductResponse {
    Product product = 1;
}

message GetProductRequest {
    string id = 1;
}

message GetProductResponse {
    Product product = 1;
}

message GetProductsRequest {
    uint64 skip = 1;
    uint64 take = 2;
    repeated string ids = 3;
    string query = 4;
}

message GetProductsResponse {
    repeated Product products = 1;
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are seeing is caused because your generated protobuf file likely has an incorrect import path.

If you check your `product.pb.go` file, it likely has a like like:

```
import "catalog/pb/entities"
```

This means it is trying to import the go package with that specified path. As you are probably familiar with, a go package must use the absolute path, so this needs to look something like:

```
import "github.com/<myuser>/<myproject>/catalog/pb/entities"
```

`protoc-gen-go` fortunately supports a couple of flags to help you with this.

**Step 1.** Set `go_package` in your `.proto` file to specify the anticipated import path in go.

```
option go_package = "example.com/foo/bar";
```

**Step 2:** use the `--go_opt=module=github.com/<myuser>/<project>` flag of `protoc` to strip the module prefix from your generated code. Otherwise you would get something like this as an output (assuming you are using the current directory as your `go_out` path

```
catalog/
  main/
  pb/
  github.com/
    <myuser>/
      <project>/
        catalog/
          pb/
            entities/
```

I would recommend reviewing the documentation page on the `protoc-gen-go` go flags: